# How do I start an out of process COM server as another (more privileged) user

Tags: com, privileges, runas

I would like to create a COM object that runs in an out of process COM server as another user. How do I do that?

I have control over the COM server source code and my COM client is the only one that will be creating these COM objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use COM+ to run objects as a network user that has certain rights we have given it (most to Windows Authentication to a SQL server.)  What this doesn't do is control who can call these objects to untilize the security we have given it.

In Vista and future, there is a COM elevation capability that does exactly what you are looking for.  Oh, looks like someone just posted that.  Follow the link they left.

Comment: Took me a while to figure out how the whole COM+ thing works, but it now seems to do whats needed. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 1):

Are you writing this for Vista?  If so, you can use a special COM invokation that runs the COM object in an elevated state.  See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms679687.aspx) article for more details.

If you are not talking about UAC, you might checkout the [CoInitializeSecurity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693736(VS.85).aspx) function.

Comment: This needs to be for any OS running Exchange Server. Windows 2003 and 2008 at least.

Answer (score 1):

Use RunAs -- see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680046(VS.85).aspx.

N.B. This setting can also be configured via dcomcnfg (Win2000) or comexp.msc (WinXP+) under "DCOM config"

If your object is implemented as an InProc server, you may combine this with a DLL surrogate (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms691260(VS.85).aspx).